# Need help displaying users' profile pics without saving them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My app uses omniaauth and the omniauth-facebook gem to connect with facebook.  I can pull down all the data I need, but I'm having trouble rendering the profile picture.

I want to show the user's profile pic by using the URL for the pic, instead of saving it to disk.

I've tried this:

```
<%= image_tag "#{@user.facebook.info.image}" %>
```

As well as this:

```
<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/<UID>?fields=picture" >
```

But neither have worked.

I haven't found anything in the facebook documentation that would prohibit me from using the URL instead of saving to disk.  Am I missing something?

Comment: your post seems to have been truncated, or otherwise incomplete!

Comment: Thanks.  Wrong indentation on the code...

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/<UID>/picture" />
```

This endpoint returns a 301 redirect to the picture. Using `?fields=` returns a json object.

Comment: This format for the link works when I manually add it to the URL address bar of the browser, but not from inside my app.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a service like [Avatars.io](http://avatars.io/) which provides the following URL patterns:

```
http://avatars.io/facebook/:id
http://avatars.io/facebook/:username
```

One thing that's nice about this approach is that it works well for other services too.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution. I had to leverage the CURB gem, which I learned about through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379700/how-to-get-302-redirect-location-in-rails-have-tried-httparty-net-http-and-re).

Ultimately, I put  this method in my application helper.

```
def redirect_location_for(url)
  uri_str = URI.encode(url)

  result = Curl::Easy.http_get(uri_str) do |curl|
    curl.follow_location = false
  end

  result.header_str.split('Location: ')[1].split(' ')[0]
end
```

And then I was able to have this in my view.

```
<%= image_tag redirect_location_for("https://graph.facebook.com/<nickname>/picture?type=square"), :size => "60x60" %>
```

Note that the solution required me to use "https" rather than "http" for the graph URL.  This ended up redirecting me to a different URL than with http and for some reason, if you're pulling the pic using HTTPS, Facebook doesn't restrict how you download and render the picture.